# Why does count(*) return multiple rows

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase

When I write sql like this:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM T1, T2
WHERE T1.Id = T2.Id
```

I get multiple rows returned:

2867

2867

2867 etc

But when I write the sql like this:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM T1
JOIN T2
ON T1.Id = T2.Id
```

I get the count as I'd expect in one row:

2867

Can anyone explain what is going on? I was expecting these two queries to return the same result.

The Sybase version is Adaptive Server Enterprise/16.0 SP03 PL11

While I can't test out `cross join` because our sybase doesn't support it, I can move the join predicate to the where clause:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM T1
JOIN T2
ON 1 = 1
WHERE T1.Id = T2.Id
```

Same result as the join with the predicate in the `ON` clause - one row

Comment: Stop and ask yourself why you're ever still writing SQL using comma joins when the explicit join syntax has been standardized *30 years ago* and every dialect has implemented them.

Comment: Please post a DBFiddle/SQLFiddle - this is curious... (does it happen in SQL Server too?)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It's still NOT supposed to happen, though. Cartesian products remain legal aside join connections. Looks rather like one of the numerous bugs I encountered while using Sybase 12.5 ASE at the time.

Comment: Looks like `count` is interpreted as a window function in the first case.
This does not happen on MySQL nor Postgres. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sVDA8Mz3hxnsB8c9KMfFQy/0
I agree that this is one of the bugs.

Comment: please update the question with Sybase RDBMS product (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and version; it may also help if you can verify you get the same response when using a different front-end/client to submt the query to the db server

Comment: I would be curious if `cross join` produced the same result as the comma join. If not, it's even clearer reason to avoid the old, non-obvious syntax and perhaps evidence that at least one product doesn't care to support it any more.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The SQL using comma joins is legacy code, not how I'd write it normally. Also our version of Sybase doesn't allow cross joins.

Comment: @markp-fuso question updated as requested

Comment: unable to reproduce the issue with `ASE 16.0 SP03 PL07` and `ASE 16.0 SP04 GA`; I'm using the `isql` command line tool; what front-end/client are you using to run your query? do you still see the issue if you use a different front-end/client (eg, command line `isql`)?